# How to open file with custom extension using my app

Tags: android

I'm stuck with one thing. I have a file with extension .xat and I want to open it using my android application. I added this to my android manifest file but I cannot open my file

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xat" />
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What's the .xat file type? If unknown for android, this file can't be opened.

Comment: It is zip archive with some data but has extension .xat

Comment: Are you sure that android can recognize that type of data ?

Comment: Have you tried adding a mime type (e.g., <data android:mimeType="*/*" /> if nothing else works).